# Scraping Table in Selenium and long single line printed instead of columns and rows

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website, and this is my code thus far:

```
import click
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

table_rows = []
url = 'https://www.iagco.agco.ca/prod/pub/en/Default.aspx?PossePresentation=PublicNoticeSearch'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Applications/Python 3.9/chromedriver')

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/span/select/option[2]").click()

driver.implicitly_wait(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a").click()

driver.implicitly_wait(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table')

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

for table in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr/td'):
    data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr/td')]
    print(data)
```

What prints out is a long list, and I am trying to figure out how to get it into a table format.

```
['City Premises Deadline for Objections / Submissions File Number Application Type Areas\nBRAMPTON Tweed\n10010 MCLAUGHLIN RD N\nBRAMPTON, ON L7A2X6 2021-09-24 1248893 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nBRAMPTON Tweed\n1990 STEELES AVE W\nBRAMPTON, ON L6Y0R4 2021-09-24 1250690 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nCAMPBELLVILLE Welcome Cannabis Campbellville\n6 MAIN ST N\nCAMPBELLVILLE, ON L0P1B0 2021-09-29 1272273 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nCANNINGTON Bud Runners Cannabis\n17 CAMERON ST W.\nCANNINGTON, ON L0E 1E0 2021-09-23 1271708 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nETOBICOKE Cannabis 151\n188 THE QUEENSWAY\nETOBICOKE, ON M8Y1J3 2021-09-20 1157846 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nETOBICOKE Fire & Flower Cannabis Co.\n764 THE QUEENSWAY\nETOBICOKE, ON M8Z0E8 2021-09-30 1211417 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nGUELPH Tweed\n138 COLLEGE AVE W UNIT A\nGUELPH, ON N1G1S4 2021-09-28 1267278 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nHAMILTON HARVEST CANNABIS CO\n318 QUEENSTON RD UNIT G\nHAMILTON, ON L8K1H5 2021-09-23 1283383 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nHAMILTON Lady Leaf\n372 KING ST E SUITE 101\nHAMILTON, ON L8N1C3 2021-09-25 1188839 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nHAVELOCK Sunfish Cannabis Trainstation\n30 ONTARIO STREET, EAST UNIT\nHAVELOCK, ON K0L1Z0 2021-10-02 1285465 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nKITCHENER THE CANNABIST SHOP – KING E\n325 KING ST E\nKITCHENER, ON N2G2L2 2021-10-04 1297162 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nMORRISBURG Morrisburg cannabis\n137 MAIN STREET\nMORRISBURG, ON K0C1X0 2021-10-01 1196780 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nMORRISBURG, SOUTH DUNDAS The Oz Store\n147 MAIN ST., UNIT #2\nMORRISBURG, SOUTH DUNDAS, ON K0C 1X0 2021-09-30 1190679 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nMORRISTON Welcome Cannabis\n3 BADENOCH ST\nMORRISTON, ON N0B 2C0 2021-10-01 1256018 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nNORTH YORK Taste Buds Cannabis\n1193 LAWRENCE AVE W\nNORTH YORK, ON M6A1E2 2021-09-25 1266788 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nOTTAWA BlueBird Cannabis Co\n27 YORK ST\nOTTAWA, ON K1N5S7 2021-10-03 1221838 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nOTTAWA Planet Earth Cannabis\n1666 BANK ST SUITE 600\nOTTAWA, ON K1V7Y6 2021-09-27 1215970 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nSTITTSVILLE SHINYBUD CANNABIS CO. STITTSVILLE\n1261 MAIN ST UNIT 2\nSTITTSVILLE, ON K2S2E4 2021-10-01 1167849 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nTORONTO BLACKSTAR CANNABIS SHUTER\n985 DOVERCOURT RD\nTORONTO, ON M6H2X6 2021-09-30 1277446 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nTORONTO Canna North Cannabis Store\n117 YONGE ST\nTORONTO, ON M5C1W4 2021-10-02 1001902 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nTORONTO Olive Jar\n554 ANNETTE ST\nTORONTO, ON M6S2C2 2021-10-02 1196618 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nWATERLOO The Cannabist Shop - Bridgeport W\n10 BRIDGEPORT RD W\nWATERLOO, ON N2L2Y1 2021-10-04 1294285 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nWELLINGTON The Community Store\n186 MAIN STREET UNIT 3\nWELLINGTON, ON K0K 3L0 2021-09-23 1252887 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission\nWINCHESTER BlueBird Cannabis Co - Winchester\n507 ST LAWRENCE ST LOWER LEVEL\nWINCHESTER, ON K0C2K0 2021-10-01 1299098 New Application\nCannabis Retail Store Authorization Indoor Area File Objection / Submission']
```

Comment: The line `print(data)` is printing a list so this output is expected.  You could loop through `data` and print each element in `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the following output as a table format.

Code:

```
import click
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

url = 'https://www.iagco.agco.ca/prod/pub/en/Default.aspx?PossePresentation=PublicNoticeSearch'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(8)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/span/select/option[2]").click()

driver.implicitly_wait(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a").click()

driver.implicitly_wait(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

t = soup.find('table', class_='possegrid')


# Get all the rows from the table
trs = t.select('tr')
for tr in trs:
    data.append(tr.stripped_strings)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0                       City                           Premises  ...  Indoor Area  File Objection / Submission
1                       City                           Premises  ...         None                         None
2                   BRAMPTON                              Tweed  ...         None                         None
3                   BRAMPTON                              Tweed  ...         None                         None
4              CAMPBELLVILLE     Welcome Cannabis Campbellville  ...         None                         None
5                 CANNINGTON               Bud Runners Cannabis  ...         None                         None
6                  ETOBICOKE                       Cannabis 151  ...         None                         None
7                  ETOBICOKE         Fire & Flower Cannabis Co.  ...         None                         None
8                     GUELPH                              Tweed  ...         None                         None
9                   HAMILTON                HARVEST CANNABIS CO  ...         None                         None
10                  HAMILTON                          Lady Leaf  ...         None                         None
11                  HAVELOCK      Sunfish Cannabis Trainstation  ...         None                         None
12                 KITCHENER        THE CANNABIST SHOP – KING E  ...         None                         None
13                MORRISBURG                Morrisburg cannabis  ...         None                         None
14  MORRISBURG, SOUTH DUNDAS                       The Oz Store  ...         None                         None
15                 MORRISTON                   Welcome Cannabis  ...         None                         None
16                NORTH YORK                Taste Buds Cannabis  ...         None                         None
17                    OTTAWA               BlueBird Cannabis Co  ...         None                         None
18                    OTTAWA              Planet Earth Cannabis  ...         None                         None
19               STITTSVILLE  SHINYBUD CANNABIS CO. STITTSVILLE  ...         None                         None
20                   TORONTO          BLACKSTAR CANNABIS SHUTER  ...         None                         None      
21                   TORONTO         Canna North Cannabis Store  ...         None                         None      
22                   TORONTO                          Olive Jar  ...         None                         None      
23                  WATERLOO  The Cannabist Shop - Bridgeport W  ...         None                         None      
24                WELLINGTON                The Community Store  ...         None                         None      
25                WINCHESTER  BlueBird Cannabis Co - Winchester  ...         None                         None      

[26 rows x 246 columns]
```